# Need help with continuity of integral in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n\in C(0,1)$ and suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on every compact subset $K\subset (0,1)$ Prove or disprove that

$\int_0^1 f_n dx\rightarrow\int_0^1 f dx $ where integrals are well defined.

I tried in the following way

$\begin{align*}
\Big|\int_0^1 f_n dx-\int_0^1 f dx\Big|&=\Big|\int_0^1 (f_n-f) dx\Big|\\
&\le ||f_n-f||_\infty\int_0^1dx\\
&\le ||f_n-f||_\infty\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}$

So

$\int_0^1 f_n dx\rightarrow\int_0^1 f dx $

Couldn't figure out what's wrong with my thinking. Any help would be 
highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that $\|f_n - f\|_\infty$ need not exist, and if it does exist need not converge to $0$.

Hint: Try $f_n(x) = (n+1) x^n$.

Comment: It would be highly appreciated if you could elaborate it. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Does this converge uniformly on compact sets?  What does it converge to?  What is its integral from $0$ to $1$?  What is the limit of that as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Very sorry for my ignorance. Still didn't get it.

Comment: Which part didn't you get?

Comment: Are you saying that $\int_0^1 f_n dx$ does not converge to $\int_0^1 f dx$.

Comment: What does it do in my example?

Comment: Using your example we get $\int_0^1 f_n dx\rightarrow 1$ and moreover $||f_n-f||_\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: ... and $\int_0^1 f\; dx = $?

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: What is the limit of $(n+1) x^n$ as $n \to \infty$ when $0 < x < 1$?